# Using jackson deserializing sealed class

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I want to deserialize below json and and value is polymorphic type

```
data class(
  val data: List<Data>
) {
  data class Data(
    val id: String,
    val value: SealedClass
  )
}
```

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "value":{
            "address":"1",
            "next":"3"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "value":{
            "count":"1",
            "option":"3"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried to use jackson @JsonTypeInfo / @JsonSubTypes
so I succeed deserializing polymorphic type when I put 'type' inside value like

```
{
  "id":2,
  "value":{
     "type": "ADDRESS",
     "address":"1",
     "next":"3"
  }
}
```

but I want to take out type and put it like below

```
{
  "id":2,
  "type": "ADDRESS",
  "value":{
     "address":"1",
     "next":"3"
  }
}
```

anyone help me?

Comment: why though? `type` is a property of the address, not of the parent object. Don't try to work against your tooling.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any way to modify the source JSON, then I think you have only one way, something like this:

```kotlin
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
    propertyNamingStrategy = PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE
    setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
}

data class Data (
    @get:JsonProperty(required=true) @field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val data: List<Datum>
) {
    fun toJson() = mapper.writeValueAsString(this)

    companion object {
        fun fromJson(json: String) = mapper.readValue<Data>(json)
    }
}

data class Datum (
    @get:JsonProperty(required=true) @field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val id: Long,

    @get:JsonProperty(required=true) @field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val value: Value
)

data class Value (
    val address: String? = null,
    val next: String? = null,
    val count: String? = null,
    val option: String? = null
)
```

And then, from non-null fields, you can deduct the actual type of Value.

But if you can, I have good news: with `@JsonSubTypes`, it's perfectly possible!

```kotlin
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = X::class, name = "x"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Y::class, name = "y"),
)
```

You need to put the `type` field inside each part of your JSON, and Jackson will figure out what type it should create itself.